# Use .pem contents in .env file

Tags: node.js, jwt

I have a next.js application where I have a local .pem file for JWT public/private key authentication. My host does not allow me to upload secret files, so I am trying to access the .pem from a muli-line string .env variable.

I have the contents of the .pem stored like this:

```
    PUB_KEY="-----BEGIN RSA PUBLIC KEY----- [newline]
    YTuFE/BOU+pF6T2nYuyYQugqJHUZ62b3LJAeZYyBIjW+LZLeHGkUOZfqHnwSbmd9[newline]
    isMbGtdNN/wujOftX1GSDApHX0LyNb+covtN4X4mcFFqyKuotFftUjOLzvb2AeJe[newline]
    s9285pXbhAKVcStyAn26pI5...[newline]
    -----END RSA PUBLIC KEY-----"
```

I get the error: `Error, secretOrPrivateKey must be an asymmetric key when using RS256`

I have tried to convert the .env variable from a multi line string to a single line string, preserving the newlines with this function:

```
    function makeSingleLineKey(key) {
      return key.replace(/(\r\n|\n|\r)/gm, '\\n'); 
    }
```

but I get the same error.

There is an issue with the formatting of the .pem key I think.

Any ideas what might be going wrong?
Thanks

Answer (score 0):

I was able to fix this by storing the .pem files in .env variables where the multi line strings were converted to a single line with the \n line breaks preserved e.g.

```
`LOCAL_AUTH_PUB_KEY={"PUB_KEY":"-----BEGIN RSA PUBLIC KEY-----\nMIICCgKCAgEAyLKk4ldt/a9dItmU2GkCVUJ1nTIh137JLTGLVyfPHkBaEBpMSm0j\nYT...`
```

I then accessed the variables in my code like this:
`const { PUB_KEY } = JSON.parse(process.env.LOCAL_AUTH_PUB_KEY)`

https://dev.to/cfofiu/how-to-store-a-long-private-key-in-vercel-s-environment-variables-46f5